# Show that $gcd(n!-1, (n+k)!-1)=1$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

How can I proceed? I've tried Bezout's identity but didn't work.

Comment: $(n+k)!-n!=k\cdot n!$

Comment: That’s not right @RezhaAdrianTanuharja

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja No, it isn't.  But  $(n+k)!-n! = n!(\frac {(n+k)!}{n!} - 1)= n![\prod_{i=1}^k(n+i)-1]$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews whoops my bad i mean $C\cdot n!$ where $C$ is a positive integer. Forgot that $k$ has been used somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$5! - 1   = 7 \cdot 17$$
$$11! - 1  = 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 23 \cdot  7853  $$

with common factor $17$

$$  \gcd( 39916799, 119 ) = 17  $$
$$ 39916799 \cdot 3 - 119 \cdot 1006306 = -17 $$

If you turn it around, Wilson's Theorem is relevant; $(p-2)! - 1$ is always divisible by $p.$  This $p-2$  is the largest possible, it is possible to have several smaller $n$ such that $n! \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Here are the first occurrences of each "count" of $n$ such that $n! \equiv 1 \pmod p.$  For prime $3011$ there are $9$  such $n.$

---

```
3 : count 0
5 : 3! - 1; count 1
29 : 10! - 1; 27! - 1; count 2
17 : 5! - 1; 11! - 1; 15! - 1; count 3
23 : 4! - 1; 8! - 1; 11! - 1; 21! - 1; count 4
199 : 81! - 1; 89! - 1; 109! - 1; 117! - 1;
      197! - 1; count 5
619 : 111! - 1; 189! - 1; 294! - 1; 429! - 1; 
       507! - 1; 617! - 1; count 6
3313 : 107! - 1; 1662! - 1; 1886! - 1; 2084! - 1; 
      2970! - 1; 3205! - 1; 3311! - 1; count 7
4093 : 557! - 1; 575! - 1; 871! - 1;
       2312! - 1;  3221! - 1; 3517! - 1; 3535! - 1;
      4091! - 1; count 8
3011 : 611! - 1; 723! - 1; 749! - 1; 
       805! - 1; 2205! - 1; 2261! - 1; 
       2287! - 1; 2399! - 1; 3009! - 1; count 9
52163 :    3924! - 1 ;  7291! - 1 ;  7427! - 1 ;
          18519! - 1 ;  24931! - 1 ;  26081! - 1 ;
          27231! - 1 ;   33643! - 1 ;  44735! - 1 ;
          44871! - 1 ;  52161! - 1 ;  count  11
```

---

Comment: Why does =1 here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd%28n%21-1%2C+%28n%2Bk%29%21-1%29 ?

Comment: @lucas Alpha is likely trying to compute their GCD _as functions_ and it can't find any common factors of either. But individual factorial-minus-1s can have non-trivial common divisors.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!